# Creating Replication Error : You cannot create a publication from server 'X' because the server is too old

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to establish a Replication from my SQL 2012 BI version but I am getting a weird error message!

> "You cannot create a publication from server 'X' because the server is too old."

Please advise?

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that you are using an older version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio connecting to a later SQL Server.

Make sure you use the SQL 2012 version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

You can use a later version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio with an earlier version of SQL, but not the reverse.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!